# How to get an array size in a function without counting or passing the length as a parameter?

Tags: c, arrays

I tried use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)`, but it seems this doesn't work if I passed the array into another function. So is there any other way to know the size of the array?

By the way: I know a `char[]` ends with `'\0'`; which character ends the `int[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an expression of array type appears in most contexts<sup>1</sup>, it is implicitly converted ("decays") to an expression of pointer type and its value is the address of the first element in the array.  Similarly, in the context of a function parameter declaration (but *only* in that context), declarations like `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are interpreted as `T *a`; despite the array notation, the parameter `a` is a pointer, not an array type.

So given code like

```
int arr[10];
...
foo(arr);
```

The type of the expression `arr` in the call to `foo` is "10-element array of `int`".  In this context, the type of the expression is converted to "pointer to `int`", so `foo` will receive a pointer value.

Similarly, given a function definition

```
void foo(int a[10])
{
  ...
}
```

the type of the parameter `a` is *not* "10-element array of `int`", but rather "pointer to `int`".

In short, you cannot pass an array argument to a function and have it received as an array type; all you get is a pointer value.  As a result, you *must* either pass the array size as a separate parameter, or terminate the array with a sentinel value (such as using a 0 in an array of `char` to terminate strings).

---

<sup>1</sup> The exceptions to this rule are when the array expression appears as an operand to either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or if it is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration.

Answer (score 4):

In C, there is a difference between an *array* and a pointer to data. When "passing an array to a function", you in effect pass a pointer to the function. Unfortunately, you can't know if a pointer points to one element, or to a sequence of elements, and it's not possible to tell how many elements the sequence consist of.

Also, unlike a string, an int array is not ended with a specific value.

Answer (score 2):

A char array only ends with a `\0` if it's being explicitly treated as a null-terminated string. There's no terminating character on arrays in general and no way to know the size of an array without passing the size around with it.